# Where are Ruby on Rails 6 scaffold templates located?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, generator, scaffold

I'm starting work on a new Ruby on Rails 6 app and I need to find the default scaffold_controller template and also the default view files: _form.html.erb, index.hmtl.erb, edit.html.erb, etc...
so that I can customize them by placing them in the /lib/templates folders.

Where are the default templates located so that I can copy them to the /lib/templates folders and modify them?

Thanks !

Comment: Scaffold view files can be found at [railties/lib/rails/generators/erb/scaffold/templates](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/66cabeda2c46c582d19738e1318be8d59584cc5b/railties/lib/rails/generators/erb/scaffold/templates)
Definitely checkout the [Rails Guide on creating and customizing generators](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html)

Comment: I did read that guide but I didn't find the location for the templates in the guide or in my newly created app. Thanks for providing the link.

Answer (score 5):

Default view template files are located at: https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/erb/scaffold/templates
Default controller template file is located at:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/scaffold_controller/templates/controller.rb.tt

In your app, put the customized view templates at: lib/templates/erb/scaffold/
Put the customized controller template at: lib/rails/scaffold_controller/

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Attempting to add custom controller scaffold.  In answer above template should be located at: lib/templates/rails/scaffold_controller/ instead of lib/rails/scaffold_controller/.  After correct path, controller scaffold worked for me

Comment: You can copy the templates to the right path just by running this command: `rake app:templates:copy `